# Is there an equivalent to the GNU linker "--just-symbols" option for non-GNU linkers?

Tags: c, macos, linker, gnu, symbols

> -R filename
>
> --just-symbols=filename
>
> Read symbol names and their addresses from *filename*, but do not relocate it or include it in  the output. This allows your output file to refer symbolically to absolute locations of memory defined in other programs. You may use this option more than once.

For example, on my Mac, `ld -R libsomething.a` or even `gcc -Wl,-R,libsomething.a` doesn't work.

Comment: Surely the answer will depend on which non-GNU linker you use, as args are processed by the specific linker invoked.

Comment: What error message are you receiving; also what linker and version are you using?

Comment: It depends on *which* "non-GNU" linker you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking about "your mac", I assume we are talking about OS X operating systems.

On UNIX-based systems the linker "[ld](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/)" (with -R option) is used most of the times (see also: [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linking_Format)).
In contrast OS X Systems use the [Mach-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) binary format and the tool [dyld](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dyld.3.html) for linking. OS X doesn't provide the same features for libraries as UNIX does. Try `otool -L` on a binary to see where the libraries are expected. You may also want to try setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (`man dyld`) for your binaries but keep in mind the security risk (this could be used to inject code like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on UNIX-systems).